# Cube drawing opengl, but a confused image of cube is drawn

Tags: opengl

Hi
I am trying to draw a cube of size 5*5*5 with six diffrent face colors. How ever,I can not see all the faces colored diffrently, all I see is a cube, with confusing colors format. 
Some faces are clearly visible, while top face , parallel to zx plane is not visible.

Thanks in advance

```
void init(void)
{
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void DrawCube(void)
{
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

//face in xy plane
glColor3f(0.82, 0.41, 0.12);//this the color with which complete cube is drawn. 
glVertex3f(0,0 ,0 );
glVertex3f(5, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(5, 5, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 0);

//face in yz plane
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 5);

//face in zx plance
glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0  );
glVertex3f(0, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 0, 0);

//|| to xy plane.
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 5, 5);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 5);

//|| to yz plane
glColor3f(0.73, 0.58, 0.58);
glVertex3f(0,0 ,5 );
glVertex3f(5, 0, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 5, 5);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 5);

//|| to zx plane //this face is not visible. I am not understanding why.
glVertex3f(0.58, 0, 0.82);
glVertex3f(0, 5, 0  );
glVertex3f(0, 5, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 5, 5);
glVertex3f(5, 5, 0);
glEnd();
glFlush();
}


void reshape(int w,int h){

glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(-1, 1, -1, 1, 1.5, 20);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

glutInit(&argc, argv);//we initizlilze the glut. functions
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
init();
glutDisplayFunc(DrawCube);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Posting is a screenshot is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//|| to zx plane //this face is not visible. I am not understanding why.
glVertex3f(0.58, 0, 0.82);
```

You want `glColor3f`. I'm guessing this is a typo.

Two unrelated things:

- Your || to xy plane quad is the same as your || to yz plane quad.
- You aren't clearing the color buffer before drawing. You probably want `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` at the start of `DrawCube`